# Netbeans IDE issue with saving

Tags: java, ide

Sometimes when I save my program before running it, on netbeans IDE it doesn't save and runs in it's previous state I checked that floppy disk icon is faded to ensure that I have saved it, this happens quite in a while and is annoying my high school teacher says that saving by clicking the floppy disk and Ctrl+S are different and recommends to use Ctrl+S, has anyone faced the same issue, any workarounds?

Please immediately notify me if my question doesn't comply with the guidelines I'll take immediate action

Comment: Which version of NetBeans IDE are you using?

Comment: It's 8.1, I have checked that it's the latest one

Comment: It seems to me that a bug in v8.1 might be causing this error as reported by many users on NetBeans forum as well. I would recommend you to upgrade it to v8.2 which is the latest one and the bug is said to have been rectified in it.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it right away

Comment: I believe the latest version is 8.2. In any case, perhaps turn on the **Save All Modified Files Before Running Ant** within Options: **Tools** --> **Options** --> **Java** --> **Ant** tab. Make sure it's check-marked.